# Connecting to the device via zkemkeeper.dll in windows application C# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, rfid, biometrics

I'm trying to connecting RFID and bio metrics devices in network, my local ip is `192.168.1.24` and the RFID device ip is `192.168.1.22`, I'm using Visual studio 12 an sample windows application. to connect this device but it throws an error:

> Unable to connect the device,error code = -201

```
private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (txtIP.Text.Trim() == "" || txtPort.Text.Trim() == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("IP and Port cannot be null", "Error");
        return;
    }
    int idwErrorCode = 0;
    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

    if (btnConnect.Text == "DisConnect")
    {
        axCZKEM1.Disconnect();

        this.axCZKEM1.OnVerify -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnVerifyEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnVerify);
        this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransactionEx -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx);
        this.axCZKEM1.OnNewUser -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnNewUserEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnNewUser);
        this.axCZKEM1.OnHIDNum -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnHIDNumEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnHIDNum);
        this.axCZKEM1.OnWriteCard -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnWriteCardEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnWriteCard);
        this.axCZKEM1.OnEmptyCard -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnEmptyCardEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnEmptyCard);

        bIsConnected = false;
        btnConnect.Text = "Connect";
        lblState.Text = "Current State:DisConnected";
        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        return;
    }

    axCZKEM1.PullMode = 1;
    bIsConnected = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net(txtIP.Text.Trim(), Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text.Trim()));


    if (bIsConnected == true)
    {
        btnConnect.Text = "DisConnect";
        btnConnect.Refresh();
        lblState.Text = "Current State:Connected";
        iMachineNumber = 1;//In fact,when you are using the tcp/ip communication,this parameter will be ignored,that is any integer will all right.Here we use 1.

        if (axCZKEM1.RegEvent(iMachineNumber, 65535))//Here you can register the realtime events that you want to be triggered(the parameters 65535 means registering all)
        {
            this.axCZKEM1.OnVerify += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnVerifyEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnVerify);
            this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransactionEx += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx);
            this.axCZKEM1.OnNewUser += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnNewUserEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnNewUser);
            this.axCZKEM1.OnHIDNum += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnHIDNumEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnHIDNum);
            this.axCZKEM1.OnWriteCard += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnWriteCardEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnWriteCard);
            this.axCZKEM1.OnEmptyCard += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnEmptyCardEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnEmptyCard);
        }

        MyCountFinger = 1;
        MyCountFace = 2;

    }
    else
    {
        axCZKEM1.GetLastError(ref idwErrorCode);
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect the device,ErrorCode=" + idwErrorCode.ToString(), "Error");
    }
    Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}
```

Please do help thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
      bool isConnected;
        try {
            isConnected = zkem.Connect_Net(ipAddr.Text, Convert.ToInt32(4370));
        } catch (Exception ext) {
            Debug.WriteLine("Холбогдож чадсангүй" + ext);
            zkem.GetLastError(ref idwErrorCode);
            if (idwErrorCode != 0) {
                getError(idwErrorCode);
            } else {
                MessageBox.Show("No data from terminal returns!", "Error");
            }
            throw new Exception();
        }

        if (isConnected) { //Here you can register the realtime events that you want to be triggered(the parameters 65535 means registering all)
            this.btnRC.Enabled = false;
            zkem.EnableDevice(1, true);
            zkem.RegEvent(1, 65535);
            this.zkem.OnAttTransactionEx += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(onAttTransactionEx);

            string sdwEnrollNumber = "";
            int idwVerifyMode = 0;
            int idwInOutMode = 0;
            int idwYear = 0;
            int idwMonth = 0;
            int idwDay = 0;
            int idwHour = 0;
            int idwMinute = 0;
            int idwSecond = 0;
            int idwWorkcode = 0;

            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            zkem.EnableDevice(1, false);//disable the device
            if (zkem.ReadGeneralLogData(1)) { //read all the attendance records to the memory
                Debug.WriteLine("Trying to open connection");
                m_dbConnection.Open();
                Debug.WriteLine("Connection Opened");
                using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(m_dbConnection)) {
                    using (var transaction = m_dbConnection.BeginTransaction()) {
                        command.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO `{0}` (`state`, `user_id`, `date`) VALUES(@state, @userID, @date)", prefix);
                        command.Prepare();
                        while (zkem.SSR_GetGeneralLogData(1, out sdwEnrollNumber, out idwVerifyMode,
                                out idwInOutMode, out idwYear, out idwMonth, out idwDay, out idwHour,
                                out idwMinute, out idwSecond, ref idwWorkcode)) { //get records from the memory

                            DateTime datetime = new DateTime(idwYear, idwMonth, idwDay, idwHour, idwMinute, idwSecond);
                            int unixDate = (Int32)(datetime.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
                            try {
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", idwInOutMode);
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", Convert.ToInt32(sdwEnrollNumber));
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", unixDate);
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                //Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
                            }
                            try {
                                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                Debug.WriteLine("inserted: " + String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2} {3}:{4}:{5}.000", idwYear , idwMonth, idwDay, idwHour, idwMinute, idwSecond));
                            } catch (SQLiteException ex) {
                                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString() +  " "+ex.StackTrace);
                            }
                        }
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                }
                m_dbConnection.Close();
                Debug.WriteLine("Connection Closed");
                Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            } else {
                Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                zkem.GetLastError(ref idwErrorCode);
                if (idwErrorCode != 0) {
                    getError(idwErrorCode);
                } else {
                    MessageBox.Show("No data from terminal returns!", "Error");
                }
            }
            zkem.EnableDevice(1, true); //enable the device
            Cursor = Cursors.Default;

            logBox.Items.Add("Холбогдлоо");
        }
```

Here is my connection code. I only use Finger print. This working good.

Comment: In here I use some local database like Sqlite for saving datas. And when i need to send them i dont need to pull datas from machine again.