# Unable to connect to zkteco fingerprint and attendance device using C#

Tags: c#, zkteco

I am trying to retrieve data from an attendance device of model number IN01 of ZKteco. I registered the zkemkeeper.dll file for x64 bit operating system. I have written a piece of code to connect it to c# application, but unfortunately it is not working.

Code:

```
bool bIsConnected = axCZKEM1.Connect_Com(1235,201, 115200); 
if (bIsConnected == true) {
   MessageBox.Show("Device Connected Successfully");
} else {
   MessageBox.Show("Device Not Connect");
}
```

but it is returning false and I am getting message from the else part.

Comment: any `Exceptions` thrown in `axCZKEM1.Connect_Com(1235,201, 115200)` ?

Comment: exception is not thrown.It returns false.Two days  since I tried fixing it but I am unable.Eagerly waiting for your help.

Comment: I tried connecting it through ip address using         bool bIsConnected = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net("192.168.100.6",4370);         .Still I am not able to connect it. When I ping the device using command prompt , it is successful.

Comment: do you have an 32bit version of that dll ?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39324911/4610605) may also be interesting. - `GetLastError()` and `Convert.ToInt32()` for your port are the first things i would check

Comment: I have a 64 bit dll . I tried using both the above methods but that didn't work. Is there anyway I can connect to attendance device using IP address? I couldn't connect using IP too.

Comment: @Hackeduser Did you find any solution ? I have the same issue today with ZKTeco Vf300

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your code.

```
 bool bIsConnected = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net(ipaddress, port);
```

Comment: @Ahmed, still getting false with no exception

Answer (score 0):

```
VARIANT_BOOL Connect_Com( [in] long ComPort, [in] long MachineNumber, [in] long BaudRate)
```

Usage

> Connect to the device via a serial port, that is, via RS232 or RS485
> port.

Note: This function can be also used for some devices that use USB Client to communicate with the PC. However, the USB client driver must be first installed to simulate a serial port. After the installation succeeds, you can view the serial port number via the device manager on the PC or find the virtual serial port number via the program. For details, see "USBClient" of the demo program from sources.